# cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [[2.]] of <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, minimize

so I have this equation I have to maximize V**2=((k*(T-k))/T)**0.5*(Y2-Y1))**2.
And Y2 and Y1 are means of the data. T is the total number of data points. To be precise k marks the breakpoint of the data, that splits it in two, thus leading the mean of the first part Y1 and the second part Y2. The data is given in a data frame(cases) with a date time index.
Here you can see my code so far:

```
def obj(k):
    Y1=cases[' New_cases'].iloc[:k+1].mean()
    Y2=cases[' New_cases'].iloc[k+1:].mean()    
    return ((k*(180-k))/180)*(Y2-Y1)

x0=0
sol=minimize(obj, x0)
```

And every time I run minimize I get:

> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [[2.]] of <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.

Is it because spicy.optimize cannot handle data frames? If so how can I circumvent this?

Also this is my first time using scipy, so if you see something else wrong or subpar in my code, please let me know.

**Edit:** I boiled down the my code to make it simpler and reproducible. The cases data frame has a date time index and one column " New_cases" containing integers.To be precise the cases file contains the number of new Covid cases for each day.

**Sample data:** >

- Date_reported  ---- New_cases
- 2020-01-03       ---   0
- 2020-01-04      ---        1
- 2020-01-05        ---      0
- 2020-01-06         ---     3

.
.
.

- 2020-07-01---4554

k also is supposed to be an integer, as it marks the position of the breakpoint in the data

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide sample data for `cases` ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). What is the type of `k`?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! I tried to provide an example of the data, hope I did it correctly, as I don't know how to upload the complete dataset. Also I tried to produce a more minimal and reproducible code example. Well k marks the position of the breakpoint in the data. So you could say the break occurred on the k-th. day. Therefore it has to be an integer. And just now I realized that that could be the problem. If k is treated as a float, one cannot minimize as the function would try all values, but you can't slice the data frame on the position 1.1 for example. But how to fix k as int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems too complicated to me. Why are you using `scipy` optimisation? This is a highly discrete problem of manageable size (memory workload and speed are negligible).

If you set

```
T = 180
```

construct a sample frame of length `T` (populated with random numbers between 0 and 10)

```
cases = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, T),
                     index=pd.date_range('2020-01-03', periods=T, freq='D'),
                     columns=['New_cases'])
```

define the objective as you did (note that it slightly differs from your original objective to *maximise* `((k*(T-k))/T)*0.5(Y2-Y1))**2`)

```
def objective(k):
    y1 = cases['New_cases'].iloc[:k+1].mean()
    y2 = cases['New_cases'].iloc[k+1:].mean()
    return k * (T - k) / T * (y2 - y1)
```

then you get the maximum/minimum by

```
objectives = [objective(k) for k in range(len(cases))]

max_objective = max(objectives)
min_objective = min(objectives)
```

and the values of `k` at which the maximum/minimum is reached by

```
k_max = [k for k in range(len(cases)) if objectives[k] == max_objective]
k_min = [k for k in range(len(cases)) if objectives[k] == min_objective]
```

(`k_max`/`k_min` are lists because it's possible that the maximum/minimum is reached several times.)

**Edit**: Illustration of the list comprehensions:

```
objectives = []
for k in range(len(cases)):
    objectives.append(objective(k))

k_max = []
for k in range(len(cases)):
    if objectives[k] == max_objective:
        k_max.append(k)
```

Comment: Well I didn't really think about just using max or min. That would give me the maximum value of the equation but how would I get k then?

Comment: OK it worked thank you very much. But I have to admit I do not fully understand the code. Could you kindly explain it? For example I am not familiar with objective(k) for k in range(len(cases)) and k for k in range(len(cases).

Comment: @Argonaut Glad I could help! The method you're asking about is called _list comprehension_. It's a _pythonic_ way to contruct lists, dictionaries, sets etc. without cumbersome loop writing. I've added 2 equivalents with the loops in the answer. My recommendation would be to read [this excellent explanation](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) from Trey Hunner. I hope this helps?

Comment: ok so basically it is a shorter way of appending a list with a for loop using an if statement. Got it. Thanks!